# mapping/Associating the users created and saved in jazn-data.xml file in an adf fusion application to the database table

Tags: oracle-adf

Is there any way by which I can map my users created in the jazn-data.xml file in adf application to the database table. Want to use query result in via method or bean return parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an sqlauthenticator in you WebLogic server (in the security realm).
If you got that working, you should be able use the default ADF Security settings to login with your users from your WLS.